# Saving double precision matrix as image

Tags: image, matlab, floating-point, double

I have a matrix of double values (e.g., 22.51, 23.15, ...) where each value corresponds to a temperature. Hence, the matrix is a thermal image. The software for the thermal camera produces a weird output format only this software can read.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How do I write the double-matrix to a graphics file such that the image quality reflects the real values in the matrix?
2. Is there a clever, memory efficient way to store the temperature values in an image (that is then also readily interpretable by windows, for example)? I suppose this might be difficult since the image formats have not enough bits per pixel? Otherwise I would have to store the temperatures in a csv file, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'the image quaility reflects the real values'? Do you simply want to create an image of the values? That's as simple as using `imagesc`. But I'm not sure that answers your first question. And I suppose an image is nothing else than a matrix, possibly with scaled data ranges and some compression. So why don't you just store the matrices as e.g. ascii files?

Comment: Hey! Yes, okay, imagesc does a nice job displaying the image. However, I have not figured out how to save/write it (in the correct size - i.e., each pixel corresponds to one matrix element). ASCII file would be an option, unfortunately this can not directly be viewed as an image by windows, for example. I was wondering if there is an image format able to store the real temperature values.

Answer (score 1):

One option for such cases is to use [FITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) instead of a standard image format. MATLAB does support reading (`fitsread`) and writing (`fitswrite`) these files, and many other programs such as ImageJ or GIMP can handle (most) .fits files.

At the most basic level:

```
I = rand(100) + 20; %100x100 matrix of doubles
fitswrite(I,'test.fits');
I2 = fitsread('test.fits'); % returns the 100 x 100 matrix of doubles
```

My personal preference, however, would be to separate out the two functions - storing data exactly, and storing an easily-viewable image. You can construct filenames using `sprintf` or just simple string concatenation. Possibly use `fileparts` to strip out just the name, minus the extension, of the original data file, then save a more easily readable (.csv) data version and a more easily viewable image version.

```
[path, name, ext] = fileparts('my_data_file.dat');
% returns name = 'my_data_file'
% if path is important, use "fullfile" function instead of below lines
fname = [name,'.csv']; % or however you store data
iname = [name, '.png']; % or preferred image format
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to FITS. I was not aware of that format. Could you elaborate on how to write the matrix to png (such that the size is preserved)?

Comment: Just pass the matrix straight to `imwrite`, but you'll need to scale it appropriately first (doubles should be 0 to 1 or you'll get weird outputs).